# How to instantiate a TableAdapter

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to instantiate a TableAdapter which is in my register dataset however I am not getting any intellisense to instantiate it?

Here is the example Microsoft uses:

```
NorthwindDataSetTableAdapters.RegionTableAdapter regionTableAdapter = 
new NorthwindDataSetTableAdapters.RegionTableAdapter();
```

My table adapter is called UsersTableAdapter and my dataset is called register, if anyone understands how I should do it that would be greatful

Comment: You have to use the correct namespace. Nobody can help you without seeing your project.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I am using System.Data; I have no code as I am just trying to instantiate the TableAdapter to continue

Comment: The `TableAdapters` get their own namespace from visual studio, for example `NorthwindDataSet.NorthwindDataSetTableAdapters.RegionTableAdapter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Table adapters are custom classes generated by VS, so you need to create your own table adapter, for more information open that link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sb6kb28.aspx

Comment: I have already created a TableAdapter hence why I said "UsersTableAdapter" and also a dataset of "register"

Comment: Try to open class view(View->Class View menu) your table adapter should be listed there. Drag and drop it in the code, this will add the full class name including the namespace. Then add the namespace with using....

Comment: It's not listed there however the dataset is listed?

Comment: Ok, then I suggest to regenerate the adapter and try again? If you don't see it in the class view that means it does not exist in your project. If you open the dataset do you see the adapter?

Comment: Yes I see the TableAdapter in there, I have created the TableAdapter again but I still can't instantiate it?

Comment: Do you see your table adapter under the table when open the dataset? See the example picture: https://i-msdn.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC22122.gif

Comment: Yup. I have my own INSERT query there also

Comment: Ok, and you see the adapter in the class view right?

Comment: Now I do, this is weird! Why wasn't it showing before?

Comment: I actually can't tell for sure, maybe the view was not refreshed properly, but now try to drag the adapter from the class view into your class.